# angularjs change button text on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table in html with multiple rows have some data format below

```
jobname     | jobid | Action
sendemail   | 34636 | Button(Name Retry)
sendereport | 35455 | Button(Name Retry)
```

In angular js controller I want to write a function when I will click on Retry button it will call some API call, I have written that one but what I need when I will click on Retry button it's button text will change to Retrying...
How to uniquely identify each button in angular js controller

Comment: Are the rows in a `ng-repeat`? Then you can specify an e.g. `boolean` attribute on the repeated items and use that to know which text to show. Would help if you showed relevant code tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ng-repeat` to show the data and when the button click you can change the name of that button.

assume this is your array

```
$scope.arr = [{"jobname":"sendemail","jobid":123, "Action":"btn1"},{"jobname":"sendReport","jobid":123, "Action":"btn2"},{"jobname":"sendWhatever","jobid":123, "Action":"btn3"}]
```

you can show the data in Dom using ng-repeat like this

```
<tr  ng-repeat="item in arr">
  <td>{{item.jobname}}</td>
  <td>{{item.jobid}}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="clickFunc(item)">{{item.Action}}</button></td> 
</tr>
```

In the click, function pass the object as parameter and change the button value

```
$scope.clickFunc = function(item){
  item.Action = "retry"
}
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.arr = [{"jobname":"sendemail","jobid":123},{"jobname":"sendReport","jobid":123},{"jobname":"sendWhatever","jobid":123}]

$scope.clickFunc = function(item){
  item.Action = "retry"
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td>jobname</td>
  <td>jobid</td>
  <td>Action</td> 
 <tr  ng-repeat="item in arr">
  <td>{{item.jobname}}</td>
  <td>{{item.jobid}}</td>
  <td><button ng-init="item.Action = 'btn'" ng-click="clickFunc(item)">{{item.Action}}</button></td> 
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we do this after removing "Action":"btn1" "Action":"btn2" and so on.. from $scope.arr and do this ?

Comment: in this scenario we can't but what is the problem with this approach

Comment: I am getting all data from mongodb, i'm not getting "Action":"btn1" from db

Comment: in that case you can use `ng-init` check the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using ng-class and in a simple way.
This is your index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
  .red{
    color:red;
  }
</style>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="abc=1" ng-class="{red:abc>0}">Click me</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this will be script.js

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

})
```

THere is no need to write special functions in controller to change color. ng-class provides inbuilt functionality.

I have also created a plunk
https://plnkr.co/edit/Koh1m6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below (Basic example during service call.):

```js
$scope.buttonLabel = "Retry";

$scope.getServiceDealData = function () {
        $scope.buttonLabel = "Retrying..";

        yourDataService.getYourServiceData().then(function (data) {
            $scope.dealData = data.deals;
            $scope.buttonLabel = "Retry";
        }).catch(function (data) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Oops! Something went wrong.";
            $scope.buttonLabel = "Retry";
        });
    }
```

Comment: where is html ?